# Oracle SQL Data Migration

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, oracle12c

Currently I'm learning how to use Oracle's SQL
And I ran into a problem which I cannot find the answer to,
I am using the SQL Developer provided by Oracle 12c and am currently using the Migration Wizard that comes with it

While trying to migrate data from MS SQL 2008 to Oracle 12c, the migration wizard tells me that the migration is complete. When I look at the repository, the tables are all moved and converted, but none of the data have been populated into the tables. I have been trying to look for migration logs, but I have not been able to find the location for the logs and I was wondering if anyone has ran into this problem before and has a solution for it.

Comment: Which migration wizard? What are you using to do the migration? What settings did you use? Not sure how you think anyone can help if we don't know what you actually did.

Comment: Sorry about that thanks for clarifying it

Comment: For your log files, have you tried looking under C:\users\your_user\appdata\roaming\sql developer\tmp?

Answer (score -2):

Just create new connection oracle connection, call it with name of migrated DB, user = , password = .

E.g. you migrate test_1 DB. After migration, create connection with name test_1,  user = test_1, password = test_1.